# Configuration location for timeout for SIGTERM handlers before killing the process when Linux shuts down

Tags: linux, configuration

I'm trying to debug a java shutdownhook problem. These shutdown hooks use SIGTERM + a watchdog thread. I suspect either a bug in the watchdog thread or a bug in my serialization process, but can't eliminate the second possibility, since i can't debug (even writing to file), so i'd like to increase the timeout to debug, but i don't know where that value is.

Edit: i'm on ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the default `SIGTERM` timeout,

For Upstart in Ubuntu, it is apparently [5 seconds](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#kill-timeout).

For `killproc` in the Red Hat family, it is apparently at least 1 + 3 = [4 seconds](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide//etc/init.d/functions). It is unclear to me if this has changed in a newer version of the function.

This answer is in the community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

According to `/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/S01halt` on my Fedora 12 system, it's 2 seconds:

```
kill_all $"Sending all processes the TERM signal..." -15 $OMITARGS
# No need to sleep and kill -9 if no processes to kill were found
if [ "$?" == 0 ]; then
    sleep 2
    kill_all $"Sending all processes the KILL signal..." -9 $OMITARGS
fi
```

On Ubuntu (10.04, at least), the code is in `/etc/init.d/sendsigs`. It waits up to 10 seconds for processes to terminate before sending `SIGKILL` to any that remain.

Rather than changing the timeout, though, it might be better to try shutting down the app yourself (`kill 12345` where `12345` is the app's PID).

Comment: Kill will not trigger the faulty code. I'm interested in debugging the timeout before killing, so i need more time (and possibly a remote debugger).

Anyway, that path doesn't exist in ubuntu.

Comment: there is a similar file:
But it doesn't use sleep at all:
...
 log_action_msg "Will now halt"
 halt -d -f $netdown $poweroff $hddown
...

I don't know the alt command, how to introduce the aditional delayy but at the same time notify the app that things are shutting down.

Comment: The similar file is : /etc/rc0.d/S90halt

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the Ubuntu location.

Are you certain that `kill` won't run the shutdown hooks? `kill <pid>` works for me.

Comment: I deleted a wrong comment. Using kill doesn't trigger the problem, only shutdown and logoff, sorry.

Comment: This is definitively a bug in the java shutdown.
I just introduced a 10 seconds sleep in the file you pointed to
(after the for in the sequence and before the if).
Java still did not write to file the shutdown (in fact i doubt it ran).